# PopupMenu not working correctly in recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
   holder.iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,  holder.iv_delete);
            MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_Popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_alert:
                           //perform operstion
                            return true;
                     case R.id.action_delete:
                          //perform operstion
                            return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });


            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });

}
```

When I click on delete button which is in red circle popup menu need to open on that button side but it open is upper side

[image]

Comment: Try `new PopupMenu(context, v);` instead of new `PopupMenu(context,  holder.iv_delete);`

Comment: @EduardoHerzer I tried, but it is not working.

Comment: @skIndia please check my ans.

Comment: @Guruji not it's not working menu open for a fraction of seconds at delete button side then it goes to upper side

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
holder.iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v, Gravity.END);

    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_Popup);

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_alert:
                           //perform operstion
                            return true;
                     case R.id.action_delete:
                          //perform operstion
                            return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });


    popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```